# Master method does not solve all questions

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

How can we solve question which could not be solved by master method
Is there any method or we should leave it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Master theorem is just a shorthand for another, more cumbersome method: approximating manually the result (i.e. thinking of the size of the recursion trees and how much time is spent in each node) and checking the result.

Answer (score 0):

There is also more general [Akra-Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method).

Of course, it has strengths, but should not be considered a “magic bullet” too.